# Why $\sum_{j=1}^mj^p \sim m^{p+1}$ as $n\to\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why $$\sum_{j=1}^mj^p \sim m^{p+1}$$ as $m\to\infty$, where $p>0$?

Comment: Should the denominator on the right side be $p+1$ rather than $n$?

Comment: No, it's strange, but it is the way it is written.

Comment: @Aryabhata Thank you for your answer! I need to understand those formulas more carefully. I'll get back once I understand the argument.

Comment: @Lionville: Ok, good to know you haven't ignored it completely :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notation is a bit confusing, but I am pretty sure the below will solve the problem you have:

You can use [Euler-MacLaurin Summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) formula, which gives us that

$$ \sum_{j=0}^{m} j^p = \int_{0}^{m} x^p dx + \frac{m^p}{2} + O(m^{p-1}) = \frac{m^{p+1}}{p+1} + \frac{m^p}{2} + O(m^{p-1})$$

For positive integral $p$, the Euler-MacLaurin formula gives us the [Faulhaber formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) very easily.